# Spring Cloud GateWay listen two port Failure

Tags: port, gateway

**spring-cloud version 2021.0.5**

**server.port=3030**

In gateway I want to listen to ports 3030 、 3031、3032, but only access 3030 after startup. my configuration

```
@configuration
public class MultiplePortConfig {

@Autowired

@Bean
public NettyReactiveWebServerFactory nettyReactiveWebServerFactory() {
    NettyReactiveWebServerFactory factory = new NettyReactiveWebServerFactory();
    factory.setPort(3031);
    factory.addServerCustomizers(new NettyServerCustomizer() {
        @Override
        public HttpServer apply(HttpServer httpServer) {
            httpServer.port(3032);
            httpServer.host("127.0.0.1");
            return httpServer;
        }
    });
    return factory;
}
```

This is also not possible with TomcatServletWebServerFactory

```
//    @Bean("tomcatServletWebServerFactory")
//    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(value = ServletWebServerFactory.class, search = SearchStrategy.CURRENT)
//    TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcatServletWebServerFactory(
//            ObjectProvider<TomcatConnectorCustomizer> connectorCustomizers,
//            ObjectProvider<TomcatContextCustomizer> contextCustomizers,
//            ObjectProvider<TomcatProtocolHandlerCustomizer<?>> protocolHandlerCustomizers) {
//        TomcatServletWebServerFactory factory = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory();
//        factory.getTomcatConnectorCustomizers()
//                .addAll(connectorCustomizers.orderedStream().collect(Collectors.toList()));
//        factory.getTomcatContextCustomizers()
//                .addAll(contextCustomizers.orderedStream().collect(Collectors.toList()));
//        factory.getTomcatProtocolHandlerCustomizers()
//                .addAll(protocolHandlerCustomizers.orderedStream().collect(Collectors.toList()));
//        Connector connector = new Connector();
//        connector.setPort(3130);
//        factory.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(connector);
//        Connector connector2 = new Connector();
//        connector2.setPort(3136);
//        factory.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(connector2);
//        return factory;
//    }
```